# Understanding the following lemma

Tags: congruences, primitive-roots, polynomial-congruences

While studying primitive roots, I came across the following lemma:

Lemma: Let $p$ and $q$ be primes and suppose that $q^\alpha\mid p-1$, where $\alpha\geq 1$. Then there are precisely $q^\alpha - q^{\alpha -1}$ residue classes $a\pmod p$ of order $q^\alpha$.

However, I also know that given a $d\mid p-1$, $x^d\equiv 1\pmod p$ has $d$ solutions ($p$ is a prime). So, is the lemma in agreement with the previous statement? Because according to the statement shouldn't it be $q^\alpha$ residue classes instead of $q^\alpha - q^{\alpha -1}$ residue classes?

Am I missing something? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Is $\alpha$ the greatest number with $q^{\alpha}|p-1$ ?

Comment: I changed a(\text{mod }p) to a\pmod p.  That is standard.  Notice that if there is more than one character after \pmod, then you need braces, as in a\pmod{43}, so that you see $a\pmod{43}$ and not $a\pmod43$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $q^\alpha$ residue classes of order *less than or equal to* $q^\alpha$.  There are $q^{\alpha-1}$ of order strictly less than $q^{\alpha}$. So there are $q^\alpha-q^{\alpha-1}$ of order *exactly* $q^\alpha$.

**Added** There are indeed $q^\alpha$ solutions of the congruence $x^{q^\alpha}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. They all have order that divides $q^\alpha$. But they do not all have order $q^{\alpha}$. For concreteness, suppose from now on that $\alpha=4$.

Note that $x=1$ is a solution of the congruence $x^{q^4}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, and $1$ has order $1$. And among the solutions of $x^{q^4}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, there are the $q$ solutions of $x^q\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. Of these, one has order $1$, and the rest have order $p$.  So  being a solution of $x^{q^4}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ does not make $x$ have order $4$.

Among the $q^4$ solutions of $x^{q^4}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ there are the $q^3$ solutions of $x^{q^3}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. There all have order a divisor of $q^3$. The rest of the solutions have order $q^4$, giving $q^4-q^3$ elements of order exactly $q^4$.

Comment: But doesn't the statement say that there are $q^\alpha$ solutions to $x^{q^\alpha}\equiv 1\pmod p$?

Comment: It certainly does. One of the solutions is $x=1$, which certainly does not have **order** $q^\alpha$. More generally, take for example $\alpha=5$. Among the $q^5$ solutions of $x^{q^5}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, there are the $q^2$ solutions of $x^{q^2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. These solutions do not have **order** $q^5$. They have order $\le q^2$.

Comment: Okay, Thanks, you clarified my doubt. +1

Comment: You are welcome.